# Best practice for protecting sensitive information on solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a field in my contract. It's something like this:

```
contract MyContract {
    string private secretField
}

function getSecretField() public view returns {
  ... some controls here...
  return secretField;

}
```

I want to reach that secretField from my backend server and protect it from any other requester. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's on a public blockchain (mainnet, ropsten testnet, ...), it's always going to be accessible by querying the [storage slot](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getstorageat) containing the `secretField` value from an **off-chain** app. No matter the Solidity `private` visibility modifier because the storage query is performed on a lower layer.

*Example: If `secretField` is the first property of the first defined contract (on this address), its value is stored in storage slot 0.*

---

But if you only want to hide it from **on-chain** requesters, you can keep the property `private` and require the getter to be accessed only from a certain address.

```
// removed `view` because it's going to interact with the transaction data
function getSecretField() public returns {
    // reverts if the sender address is not 0x123
    require(msg.sender == address(0x123);

    return secretField;
}
```

Note that your backend app is going to have to `send` a transaction from the `0x123` address in order to access the data. Simple `call` won't return anything because the `getSecretField()` is not a `view` function anymore.

Comment: It will be on the public blockchain. strage_slot method makes protecting impossible. I think I need to find another pattern.

Comment: @MiratCanBayrak Maybe your use case will allow for hashing - (publicly) store just a hash of some secret and validate against the hash (mind that transactions are public too, so you might also want your users to pass the hash - not the value before hashing such as password). But generally speaking, public blockchains are not a good way of storing private data.