# Is it safe to store passwords as mappings in Solidity?

Tags: passwords, solidity

I want to have accounts system in my solidity program, is it safe to store password in a mapping? (eq. bellow)

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Passwordtest{
    //some code
    mapping (address => string) private passwd;
    function Authentication(string _passwd) {
        //compare the passwords and do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice for protecting sensitive information on solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460613/best-practice-for-protecting-sensitive-information-on-solidity)

Answer (score 0):

As the link in the comment of Petr Hejda says, there's no way of preventing someone to read in your contract state, you could store the password as a hash but anyway the transaction and the data is public so anyone could see the password when is sended